# How to run Selenium test using Edge headless

Tags: selenium, unit-testing

Some time ago, I wrote some Selenium unit tests and these used the Firefox browser (headless). After a few years, I have returned to these *(and cannot now remember how they worked)* and would like to update them to use the Edge browser (in headless mode). How do I do this ? Specifically, when I ask the IWebDriver to "Navigate", how does it know the root URL - specifically the port ? I presume that my URL would be "http://localhost:*nnnn*/blah...", but how do I determine the port (which I also presume I need) ?

My code is based upon the following:

```
protected IWebDriver GetBrowserEdge(bool headless = true)
{
    var service = SeleniumTools.EdgeDriverService.CreateChromiumService();
    service.UseVerboseLogging = true;

    var options = new SeleniumTools.EdgeOptions { PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal, UseChromium = true };
    if (headless) options.AddArgument("headless");

    return new SeleniumTools.EdgeDriver(service, options);
}
```

I wasn't using "CreateChromiumService" before (and I note it is disposable - which gives me a design issue), but I note that the service it returns has a "port" property. Do I need to leverage that in my "IWebDriver.Navigate" calls ?

I am using Edge v92.0.902.73 and Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools v3.141.2

Comment: only Edge Chromium supports headless.  (Though I think it's moved entirely over to chromium based now?)  You should be able to set that just as you would for chrome.   Port doesn't matter on a navigate or get... just give it a url.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

Comment: Hi, that msft post was what I used to setup my code. When I call "navigate" I get "unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  (Session info: headless MicrosoftEdge=92.0.902.73)"
...   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)

Comment: localhost may be used by the webdriver/wire protocol.   Try using "127.0.0.1" instead.  (I assume you are testing a locally hosted site here?)